# cannot call variable in simple R loop

Tags: r, for-loop

attempting to do this simple loop:

```
#a,b,c,d and e are datasets i want to normalize
list <- list(a,b,c,d,e)
     
    for(i in list) { 
        i <- Normalize(i) }
```

I hoped to have as a result that my datasets a,b,c,d and e would be normalizes, however, "i <-" ended up not being read as an occurrence in the list, but instead created a dataset called "i" containing the last occurrence in the list. for bash I would usually call the variable as $i, but here i could not find how to properly call it.

Comment: Can you please add an example that illustrates what you expect, including input and output? As it stands right now it's unclear if you want `i` as counter or data item.

Comment: It looks like you want `lapply(list(a,b,c,d,e), Normalize)`

Comment: Hi, I updated it! I hope now it is clearer. I wanted "i" to call for the datasets in the list

Comment: Alternatively, try `for(i in seq_along(list)) list[[i]] <- Normalize(list[[i]])`

Comment: @AllanCameron Unfortunately that does not update the dataset itself

Comment: @ubuntunoob it does (it updates the members of `list`). It doesn't update the individual objects in the global environment of course, but it's better not to do that in R. Keep objects you want to iterate over in a list rather than as individual objects in the global environment. As a last resort you could do something like `for(i in c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')) assign(i, Normalize(get(i)))` if you want to iterate through objects in the global environment, but this is considered bad practice in R.

Comment: Understood! thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are copying each dataset to the `i` variable and modyfying this variable at each loop iteration, leaving the initial list unedited. At the end of the loop you just getting the last `i` value.

You need to use counter instead and access the elements of the list, using this counter in `for` loop like:

```
for(i in 1:length(list)){
    list[[i]] <- Normalize(list[[i]])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `lapply` function to normalize a list of datasets instead of a loop. A loop is usually less efficient with R.

```
list_of_datasets <- list(a, b, c, d, e)
list_of_datasets_normalized <- lapply(list_of_datasets, Normalize)
```